# How to add specific permission view to certain users based on their field in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

So basically i have to make sure Users that are from the same department field to view and create any datas in the database. Not sure how to apply it using field-based user permissions?

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'
    company          = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    contact          = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    branch           = models.ForeignKey('generals.Branch', 
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department       = models.ForeignKey('generals.Department', 
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by       = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    modify_by        = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    modify_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    is_active        = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, 
                           blank=True)
    is_superuser     = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, 
                           blank=True)
    is_staff         = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, 
                           blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use what's already implemented in Django, and you'll gain a lot of time.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company     = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact     = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch      = models.ForeignKey('generals.Branch', 
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department  = models.ForeignKey('generals.Department', 
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by  = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    modify_by   = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

even though my eyes are burning because my syntax here is not PEP8 compliant, you should get the big picture: all the permissions are already handled by `User` and `Group`.

Just create a Group that has the name of the company, and give this group access (or not) to specific tables.